# Global variable gets changed , if we assign it to local variable and changing local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, global-variables

```
$permission = YAML.load_file('permission.yml').deep_symbolize_keys

local_permission = $permission['packing'.to_sym] 

local_permission['create'] = ['so1']
```

I am changing create of `local_permission` variable, but it gets changed into `$permission`. I don't want this. Please help me to solve this.

I am expecting that `$permission['create']` should remain same even after changing `local_permission['create']`.

Comment: `'packing'.to_sym` is not necessary when you could just use `:packing` (literal `Symbol`) additionally `local_permission['create']` will not modify `$permission['create']` it will add a new key `'create'` to `$permission` because you called `deep_symbolize_keys` so all `keys` are `Symbol`s and `'create'` is not a `Symbol`. e.g. You will end up with `{:create => ['original'], 'create' => ['so1']}`

Answer (score 2):

You need to duplicate the original object, right now you're only assigning a reference to it.

You can use:

```rb
local_permission = $permission[:packing].clone
local_permission[:create] = ['so1']

# or if you're using rails and want everything to be cloned:

local_permission = $permission[:packing].deep_dup
local_permission[:create] = ['so1']
```

Comment: Worth noting that the first one is shallow. Additionally `dup` and `clone` are not *exactly* the same (although in this case that is incosequential). Given `$permission` appears to be a `Hash` one of the simplest ways to "deep_dup" a `Hash` in standard ruby is `local_permission  = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump($permission))`

Comment: Will it change the original $permission after changing local_permission ?